# Facebook sdk python outputting access token without login?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a python reaction tester and I wish to share scores to facebook, however the sdk is confusing me greatly. I have got an access token without prompting a log in page, and the token appears in the web browser instead of the login. This is the code I have and an [image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAB1T.png):

```
def facebookShare():
appID = '[removed]'
appSecret = '[removed]'
authArguments = dict(client_id = appID,
                     client_secret = appSecret,
                     redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/',
                     grant_type = 'client_credentials',
                     state='abc123')
authCommand = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(authArguments)
authResponse = os.startfile(authCommand)

try:
    authAccessToken = urllib.parse.parse_qs(str(authResponse))['access_token']
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=authAccessToken, version="3.2")
    facebookResponse = graph.put_wall_post('I got an average time of ' + averageTime + 'seconds!')
except KeyError:
    errorWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(root, bg = "blue")
    tkinter.Label(errorWindow, text = "Something Went Wrong.", bg = "red").pack()
```

Shouldn't it need to log in to generate the access token? How can I make this generate a log in so it can print to the user's wall how it is supposed to? What URL would I need to use to get a login dialog?

Comment: _“Shouldn't it need to log in to generate the access token?”_ - for a user token, yes. But the endpoint you are using here is for issuing app tokens only to begin with …

Comment: Ah, so from here I need to use this access token to get the user token? That makes sense, thanks

Comment: No, you get a user token by implementing the login flow. The app access token is not directly involved in that process.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, how can I change what I have in order to get a login dialog rather than the app access token?

Comment: Best if you check the documentation for whatever python library you are using there first. Facebook of course has its own documentation that describes how to implement login (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/), but you don’t want to work around or against your framework, so check what the docs for that suggest first.